# 35 "Flash Player" in DiskUtility

Tags: macos, disk-utility, dmg, adobe-flash

from `sudo diskutil list` I get 35 of these

```
/dev/disk35 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +17.9 MB    disk35
1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk35s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Flash Player            17.9 MB    disk35s2
```

`sudo diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk35` gives a hopeful `Unmount of all volumes on disk35 was successful`, but if I list it is still there.

Any idea why this happens? and how to get rid of these Flash Player images?

Cheers,
Roberto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disk "Flash Player" is still attached to the filesystem. Go into `/Volumes`, and you should see it there. There are two ways to proceed, the GUI method, or the command line method. Use whichever you are most comfortable with.

GUI: Navigate to `/Volumes` and press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. This will eject the volume.

CLI: `diskutil eject /dev/diskx`, in this case `disk35`. This will also eject the volume.

---

The difference between `diskutil unmountDisk` and `diskutil eject` is that `unmountDisk` only ceases disk-IO between the disk and the filesystem, but keeps it attached so that it can be mounted later. However, `eject` effectively 'removes' it from the filesystem, and remounting it may involve physically reconnecting the disk. Think of them as "stand by" and "shutdown" respectively on a computer.

From `man diskutil`:

> diskutil eject
>
> Eject a disk.  Media will become offline for the purposes of being a data store for file systems or being a member of constructs such as software RAID or direct data.  Additionally, removable media will become eligible for safe manual removal; automatically-removable media will begin its physical (motorized) eject sequence.

whereas

> diskutil unmountDisk
>
> Unmount an entire disk (all volumes).  Force will force-unmount the volumes (less kind to any open files; see also umount (8)).  You should specify a whole disk, but all volumes of the whole disk are attempted to be unmounted even if you specify a partition.

Comment: nothing shown in `/Volumes` except `Macintosh HD`

Comment: still `diskutil eject /dev/diskx` worked.

Comment: A little bit of research and live experimenting shows that even though the disk image may be unmounted, it can still be seen in `diskutil list`. Interestingly, the same behaviour can be observed in hard disks that have been "ejected". Both unmounted/ejected media can still be remounted through `diskutil mountDisk`, which has me thinking they're still "attached" to a `/dev` node.